# Advanced All In One .NET Framework (should i go for a software factory ?)

Tags: .net, winforms, unit-testing, nhibernate

i m starting a new project that would basically take input from user and save them to database among about 30 screens, and i would like to find a framework that will allow the maximum number of these features out of the box :

- .net c#.
- windows form.
- unit testing
- continuous integration
- logging
- screens with lists, combo boxes, text boxes, add, delete, save, cancel that are easy to update when you add a property to your classes or a field to your database.
- auto completion on controls to help user find its way
- use of an orm like nhibernate
- easy multithreading and display of wait screens for user
- easy undo redo
- tabbed child windows
- search forms
- ability to grant access to some functionnalities according to user profiles
- mvp/mvvm or whatever design patterns
- either some code generation from database to c# classe or generation of database schema from c# classes
- some kind of database versioning / upgrade to easily update database when i release patches to application once in production
- automatic control resizing
- code metrics analysis
- some code generator i can use against my entities that would generate some rough form i can rearrange after
- code documentation generator
- ...

At this point i have 3 options :

- Build from scratch on top of clr :(
- Find functionnalities among several open source framework and use them as a stack for infrastucture
- Find a "software factory"

I know its lot but i really would like to use existing code to build upon so i can focus on business rules.

What open source tools would u use to achieve these ?

About software factories,  is there any free one ? Open source is not mandatory but would be nice.

Comment: Visual Studio + c# + Linq-to-entities + database of your choice. Yeah, you would have to write some things yourself, but unfortunately there is no 'put business logic in, get complete application out' program/framework. :)

Comment: You exactly got my point. :)
I am looking for the closest thing to 'put business logic in, get complete application out'.
What would u suggest for gui ? 
My only whish here is to have automatic control resizing when i change windows and font sizes.

Comment: if you want "put business logic in, get application out", then what you're looking for is a software house, not a framework. There is no framework that will do this for you.

Comment: So you mean you are looking for a software developer? Maybe you should post this on a job board instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Paco :) :
I would like to be able to have a quick infrastructure setup so i won t need a second developper. If not are you available ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your list you are looking for a 4GL language (if it should be .Net e.g. PowerBuilder or DataWindow .NET).

There is no "framework" that could do that.

Comment: I gave a look at DataWindow.NET and it seems to fullfill my needs.
Have u tried it ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [DevExpress eXpressApp Framework](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/)?

It will not do everything you have on your list, but it is a framework which allows you to create applications of a particular format pretty fast, with full C# and .NET programmability. Think of it like a sort of access-for-.net type of framework.

Comment: Watching the tutorials video now, i wonder have long it would take to add a screen targeting a new business entity once all the infrastucture has been set up. Fast developpement is one thing, easy maintenance is another.